# passing a variable between files

Tags: lilypond

I'm running into an issue trying to pass a variable between three files. For example:

- in fileA.ily I have the variable `number = "3"`
- in fileB.ly I have the statement `\include "fileA.ily"` and `\include "fileC.ily"`
- in fileC.ily I have the statement `{c'4 \mark \markup { \number }`.

And this works fine. When I compile fileB, the variable `number` gets picked up. The problem I'm running into, though, is when I use a more complicated scheme-style `\include` statement in fileB. For example:

```
#(define subdir "somefolder")
#(define subdir2 "somefolder2")
\include #(string-append "firstDir/" subdir "/filename" ".ily")
\include #(string-append "firstDir/" subdir2 "/filename" ".ily")
```

When I use these kinds of includes, then when I compile fileB, it performs the includes correctly but doesn't find the number variable like it did in the first example. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried embedding the fileC statement within a scheme expression? My thought is whether there's an issue of when (scheme) expressions are being evaluated: during compilation vs. at run-time.

Comment: Aaron, thanks, I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: One other thought. How about changing fileA to be a scheme function called "number" that returns "3"?

Answer (score 4):

I’m rather surprised that the first version works for you. Basically the problem is that `\number` is already defined as a markup command. During parsing of markup statements Lilypond will first try to evaluate a command `\abc` as markup command and then (if no such command exists) try to scope it. This means that in your example Lilypond should always try to call the `\number ...` markup command, and fail due to no argument being passed. This behaviour can be seen in this example:

```
\markup "Default:"
\markup \draw-hline

\markup "Overriding \draw-hline:"
draw-hline = "abc"
\markup \draw-hline

\markup "Using \draw-hlineb instead:"
draw-hlineb = "abc"
\markup \draw-hlineb
```

You’ll see that overriding the markup command `draw-hline` will not in fact affect the output.

There are multiple things you can do to circumvent this: Instead of doing `number = "3"` you could redefine the markup command like this `#(define-markup-command (number layout props) () (interpret-markup layout props "3"))`, although it is arguable whether this is really a good way to do it. You could also change the name of the variable to something that is not a markup command, like `NUMBER`. Then you could also explicitely force the parser to scope the `number` variable. This can be done by not using `\number`, but `#number`, which explicitely tells the parser to evaluate the scheme expression `number`, which then scopes for a binding to `number`. So instead of `{c'4 \mark \markup { \number }}` you’d do `{c'4 \mark \markup { #number }}`.

Comment: When I left my comments for the OP, I looked to see if `\number` was predefined, but didn't find it. What is it for?

Comment: Look in https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/lilypond-command-index.

Comment: @Aaron As can be seen in the docs linked by Jean `\number ...` is used to switch the font style for the argument to Lilypond’s special number style, used for Time Signatures, Fingerings &c.